# Putting packages in @ComponentScan(basePackage = { "xxx.yyy.zzzz" })

Tags: spring-mvc

I have multiple packages under src/ folder, e.g. controller, dao, service. How do I provide them in

```
@ComponentScan(basePackage = {
    "xxx.yyy.zzzz"
})
```

[My package Explorer looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osG39.png)

Comment: Those are resources (which usually don't live in packages). Component Scan is for annotated classes, which do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look like this `@ComponentScan({"dao","services","controller"})`